# TrustedAuthenticationRequest

Tags: quarkus, forms-authentication

Using Quarkus 3 with the Primefaces extension to build a JSF application.  Quarkus has been set up to use form based authentication and based on review of source code, the FormAuthenticationMechanism returns credential types of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationRequest and TrustedAuthenticationRequest, both of which I've implemented.

Not sure how the TrustedAuthenticationRequest is supposed to work.  When requesting a faces page, the identity provider for TrustedAuthenticationRequest is called multiple times, seems like once for every resource (css, js, etc....).  The identity provider code is listed below.  It sets the principal and roles each time it is called which seems excessive (one page resulted in more than 10 calls).

Is this the expected behavior or am I implementing something wrong here?

Thanks

```
@Override
    public Uni<SecurityIdentity> authenticate(TrustedAuthenticationRequest request,
            AuthenticationRequestContext authenticationRequestContext) {
        
        if (Objects.nonNull(request.getPrincipal())) {
            return Uni.createFrom().item(QuarkusSecurityIdentity.builder()
                    .setPrincipal(new QuarkusPrincipal(request.getPrincipal()))
                    .addRoles(Set.of("create", "read", "update", "delete"))
                    .build());
        }

        throw new AuthenticationFailedException("password invalid or user not found");
    }
```